# Is it possible to extract a UUID from a response in Jmeter so I can use for a subsequent request

Tags: api, jmeter, jmeter-3.2

My Scenario:

1. I am doing a POSt request that generates a rateID( UUID)
2. Doing another POST request that uses this rateID
3. I am also using 2 other fields in the body that is getting extracted by JSON Extractor but somehow this rateID is just getting passed as is

### Sample Response body from 1st POST request

```
{
        "source": "USD",
        "target": "MXN",
        "RateId": "0f4a78a2d2b34849882f0154b9249345",
        "exchangeRate": 21.3909440000,
        "rateExpiry": "2020-09-14 20:30:20",
        "providerId": 2,
        "providerNm": "ZIGA-STATIC",
        "rawRate": 21.3376000000,
        "markupValue": 0.00250
 }
```

### Sample request body from 2nd POST request

```
[{

  "source":"${source}",
  "target":"${target}",
  "RateId":"${RateId}",
  "buyAmount":100,
  "transactionSettlementDate":"2020-07-28",
  "transactionId":"${GUID}",
  "transactionTimestamp":"2020-07-28T17:35:17.866Z"

}]
```

### Getting error

```
{"errorMessages":["Transaction #0: [invalid RateId ${RateId}]"]}
```

IS it not possible to use UUID like that?? I even tried using a Regex for extracting UUID
([a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-4[a-f0-9]{3}-[89aAbB][a-f0-9]{3}-[a-f0-9]{12}) but still no luck

Asking help from Jmeter experts in the community, please help

Answer (score 0):

From what you show, it looks like extraction of the 4 fields did not work.

You need to add to the first HTTP request 3 JSON extractors:

First one with for source variable with json path expression :

[image: source]

Second for target variable :

[image: target]

Last one for RateId

[image: RateId]

For Guid, it's not clear if it's just the value of RateId (why did you create a variable Guid and not just used ${RateId} and how is it filled in this case ?).

If it’s just a random uuid, you can use function UUID:

> ${__UUID()}

Otherwise clarify where it comes from.

See:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID

Answer (score 0):

You can extract 3 values in a single shot using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the following Groovy code:

```
def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

vars.put('source', response.source)
vars.put('target', response.target)
vars.put('RateId', response.RateId)
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)